# Containerless control flow syntax - the templates don't render properly with IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

When using containerless syntax and calling a Knockoutjs template, the IE8 doesn't render properly a template inside a foreach control flow. The initialization works ok, but if the `items` are changed, then the rendering is wrong. This happens only on IE8, 9 is ok, even 7 works.

**Model**

```
function BrowseModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.itemsStep = ko.observable(1);
    self.repopulate = function() {
        self.itemsStep(self.itemsStep() + 3);
        return false;
    };
    ko.computed(function() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = self.itemsStep(); i <= self.itemsStep() + 5; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        self.items(arr);
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new BrowseModel());
```

**View**

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-bind="click: repopulate">Change items</a>
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->                                                 
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'product_template'} -->
        <!-- /ko -->  
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<ul>
    <li data-bind="template: { foreach: items, name: 'product_template' }"></li>
</ul>


<br />
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>


<script type="text/html" id="product_template">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</script>
```

I didn't find some pattern how IE 8 behaves. The rendering is kind random.

Beside not using the containerless control flow syntax, how can I fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7CK9/36/)

*LE: I'm using F12 Developer Tools if this does matter*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7CK9/37/)

I've added a `&nbsp;` to the inner binding and it seems to have fixed the problem. It seems like knockout in IE8 does not like nested containerless control bindings that have no content.

Note, in my experience, **containerless control bindings tend to show erratic behavior in IE6-IE8**. If you intend to support these browsers, I suggest you avoid containerless control bindings. Nearly all scenario's that involve containerless control bindings can be rewritten to an alternative with a HTML element with a data-bind expression.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I was going to do this in the end. I hope this trick is not mentioned in docs, so I won't blame myself for not reading the entire documentation..

Comment: Don't sweat it. I've noticed plenty of "peculiar" behavior with the containerless control bindings in the older IE browsers. Most of these could be solved by either removing whitespace/linebreaks or introducing some arbitrary HTML content. In the end, I just rewrote most of my containerless control bindings to data-bind expressions on elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with this structure in IE8. When I tried to keep the containerless stuff separate as you show in the original post, IE8 complained. By using the syntax shown below, it works fine.

```
<table id="mam-listing-table" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="">Team</th>
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="" colspan="99">Note Count</th>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap=""></th>

            <!-- ko foreach: Months -->
                <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="" data-bind="text: $data "></th>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="" data-bind="text: 'TOTAL as of ' + moment().format('MM/DD/YY')"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <!-- ko template: { name: 'Site', foreach: Sites} -->
        <!-- /ko -->  
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'Total'} -->
        <!-- /ko -->  

    </tbody>

</table>
```